# how to retrieve item from array list that is a constructor parameter

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I have a class of menu items that lists the price, description, and categories. i want the categories to be in a set array list so that there are only 3 to choose from. I'm not sure how to put this into my l constructor or pull that information out.

Example: here are my fields and constructor for menu items

```
private double price;
private String description;
private ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Appetizer", "Main Course", "Dessert"));

//set constructor
public MenuItem(double price, String description, ArrayList<String> category){
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
    this.category = category;
    //do i not put the arraylist into my constructor or is this is correct?  
}
```

i know if i want to get the price from a menu item i do that like so

```
    MenuItem lobsterRisotto = new MenuItem(14.99, "Lobster pasta in buttery red sauce");

    //print the price of lobster risotto
    System.out.println(lobsterRisotto.getPrice());
```

but i am not sure how to get a specific category from the arraylist

Comment: You don’t add it in the constructor and you should also declare it `final` since you are not going to change it and also static since it will be common (a single version) for all MenuItem objects. `private static final ArrayList<String> category =...`

Comment: okay thank you! then how would i go about accessing one of the items from another class? say i wanted to grab the category dessert when making an instance of a menuitem inside of my main?

Comment: Then you either make it public or add a get method `public static List<String> getCategories()`

Comment: See also my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59868021/9223839) to a similar question

Comment: By doing that System.out.println(lobsterRisotto.getCategory()); will give me the full array [appetize, main course, dessert] but I guess what I'm not understand is how to pull just appetizer from that because the getter will pull the entire array and i'm not sure how to get an index of that array

Comment: What you should have is a separate instance variable to hold the category for each MenuItem instance, `private String category ` for instance. Maybe it is also better to use an enum than a list as mentioned in one of the answers to hold your different categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define multiples constructors.

You are assigning default values when you defines lines such as:

```
private ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Appetizer", "Main Course", "Dessert"));
```

Here an example that illustrates the behavior with multiple constructors:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MenuItem {
    private double price;
    private String description;
    private ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Appetizer", "Main Course", "Dessert"));

    public MenuItem(double price, String description) {
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public MenuItem(double price, String description, ArrayList<String> category) {
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MenuItem lobsterRisotto1 = new MenuItem(14.99, "Lobster pasta in buttery red sauce - sample 1");
        MenuItem lobsterRisotto2 = new MenuItem(
                29.99,
                "Lobster pasta in buttery red sauce - sample2",
                new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("category1", "category2", "category3")));

        // output: 14.99
        System.out.println(lobsterRisotto1.getPrice());
        // output: 29.99
        System.out.println(lobsterRisotto2.getPrice());

        // output: Appetizer, Main Course, Dessert
        System.out.println(lobsterRisotto1.getCategory().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

        // output: category1, category2, category3
        System.out.println(lobsterRisotto2.getCategory().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution each instance of MenuItem will hold its own copy of the array list which is a waste of memory since the list is exactly the same for each instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Joakim Danielson and the answer depends on how many categories can have a MenuItem. Also is a good idea consider creation patterns like Factory or Builder combined with Java Enums, but those topics are advanced comparing with the scope of the question/thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use an ArrayList if it is supposed to hold three and only three possible values. Just use a static final Sting array. Better yet, use an enum.

Then your constructor should have as a parameter a String (or enum value) (not an ArrayList), and it should check that that value is one of the three legal values in categories. If you used an enum, that check would be done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To access a specific array list item here is what i did

in my getter i return a string because that is the type of item i am trying to retrieve and set the paramter of the getter to an int to access that index number

```
    public String getCategory(int i) {
        return category.get(i);
```

then to acess a specific index from an instance i created in main (for this example it was appetizer in the 0 index position of the array) i used

```
        System.out.println(lobsterRisotto.getCategory(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the desired behavior, I suggest not using a `List<String>` to hold the valid possible menu item categories.  You could easily do this using an [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and this would also give the ability to perform actions on the given type if desired.

```
enum MenuCategory {
    APPETIZER("Appetizer"),
    MAIN_COURSE("Main Course"),
    DESSERT("Dessert");

    private final String displayName;

    MenuCategory(final String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public final String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

I would then use a base abstract class and create subclasses for each type.  This would ensure each MenuItem constructed is created with the correct category and also give you the ability to perform actions specific to the subclass. [Abstract class example](https://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java) [Inheritance information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

```
abstract static class MenuItem {
    protected final double price;
    protected final String description;
    protected final MenuCategory category;

    public MenuItem(final double price, final String description, final MenuCategory category) {
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        // Protect against a subclass being made that does not pass in a MenuCategory value.
        this.category = Objects.requireNonNull(category);
    }

    public final double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public final String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public final MenuCategory getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return category.getDisplayName() + ": " + description + " " + price;
    }
}

static class AppetizerItem extends MenuItem {
    public AppetizerItem(final double price, final String description) {
        super(price, description, MenuCategory.APPETIZER);
    }
}

static class MainCourseItem extends MenuItem {
    public MainCourseItem(final double price, final String description) {
        super(price, description, MenuCategory.MAIN_COURSE);
    }
}

static class DessertItem extends MenuItem {
    public DessertItem(final double price, final String description) {
        super(price, description, MenuCategory.DESSERT);
    }
}
```

And finally, to create a MenuItem you could do

```
MenuItem lobsterRisotto = new MainCourseItem(14.99, "Lobster pasta in buttery red sauce");

//print the price of lobster risotto
System.out.println(lobsterRisotto.getPrice());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you won't actually be passing a list in the constructor (only the type) adding category would be wrong. I would say make the the category array list a global variable, and then use that.